# What type of rotation is this and how do I apply it?

Tags: opengl, java, rotation, lwjgl

I'm developing a 3D game in Java using LWJGL and JOML. In order to simplify player and NPC coding, I'm representing their orientation as two scalar quantities: "direction" and "angle" (maybe not the best names). "Direction" is the compass direction that the object is facing, and "angle" is the angle of the object relative to a horizontal plane. So for example if a player has a direction of 180 and an angle of 45, it will be looking south at a point halfway between the horizon and the zenith.

**First question: what is this kind of rotation called officially?**

I've already written code to handle calculations on points/positions represented in this manner, but I don't know how to include the rotation in a transformation matrix for OpenGL. I have the following code to produce a transformation matrix for an object:

```
Matrix4f world_matrix = new Matrix4f().identity().translate((float) position.x, (float) position.z, (float) -position.y).rotateY((float) Math.toRadians(-direction));
```

(same code, more readable)

```
Matrix4f world_matrix = new Matrix4f()
    .identity()
    .translate((float) position.x, (float) position.z, (float) -position.y)
    .rotateY((float) Math.toRadians(-direction));
```

where `position` is the location of the object and `direction` is the aforedescribed "direction" of the object.

**Second question: how do I include `angle` in `world_matrix`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're using are called [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). Euler angles can tell the direction of a vector (in your case the direction that an object is facing) with 2 angles, one around the Y axis (yaw) and 1 around the X axis (pitch).

A common misconception is that Euler angles consist of angles around the X, Y and Z axes, but what those are really called are Tait-Bryan angles.

You can include your "angle" in the world matrix by rotating around the X axis after the rotation around the Y axis (using the `rotateX` method at the end of your transformation chain). Note that the transformation methods in JOML act after any existing transformations already applied to the matrix, so `rotateX` will rotate the object about its local X axis (to set the object's rotation relative to the global coordinate space use one of the "setRotation" methods).

Comment: I've done that for my camera angle but it doesn't work for objects (as I originally expected it wouldn't) because the `angle` rotation isn't about the global X axis but about the local (object-relative) X axis. `.rotationX()` rotates the object about the global X axis.

Comment: I don't understand why `Matrix4f().identity().rotateX((float) Math.toRadians(-angle)).rotateY((float) Math.toRadians(direction)).translate((float) -position.x, (float) -position.z, (float) position.y)` works for the camera matrix but `Matrix4f().identity().translate((float) position.x, (float) position.z, (float) -position.y).rotateX((float) Math.toRadians(angle)).rotateY((float) Math.toRadians(-direction))` doesn't work for an object's transformation matrix (the object ends up "sideways" as `direction` moves away from 0).

Comment: Never mind I've got it now - I put `.rotateX()` after `.rotateY()` and now it works. I thought the rotations were independent of each other (i.e. that `.rotateX()` means "set the rotation about the X (global) axis") but they're not (i.e. `.rotateX()` actually means "rotate the object about the (local) X axis, taking into account any existing rotations").

Comment: I will once my edit has been accepted (as it is it isn't worthy of accepting, because it's too confusing to answer the question by itself).

Comment: @MichealJohnson I already accepted ages ago

Comment: I didn't realise that, sorry.

Comment: I wonder why this answer has -1 score. Could the downvoter provide some explanation?

Comment: @Mars It used to be somewhat ambiguous and confusing (I'm not the downvoter).

Comment: OK, but people shouldn't act like "give down vote to this, give down vote to that". They should at least comment their decision. Better, they should participate in process of improving the answer. Leaving trail of downvotes is way to kill the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Timelord64 I **never** said Euler angles are 2D only, I only said that Euler angles only have angles around 2 axes and not 3. Please, don't downvote a question without reading it completely or without understanding the topic completely.

Comment: @MichealJohnson It never was ambigious either. It depends on you in wich order you apply rotations. By applying the X rotation first then the Y you essentially rotate the cube on it's local Y axes instead of doing thr same with the X.

Comment: @Timelord64 "A common misconception is that Euler angles consist of angles around the X, Y and Z axes, but what those are really called are Tait-Bryan angles." Yes, Tait-Bryan angles are a variation of Euler angles and I never said something different from this. Just because Tait-Bryan angles are a variation of Euler angles and Tait-Bryan angles have 3 angles, that doesn't mean that Euler angles have 3 angles. In this case he uses Euler angles because (the x-y-x variation) because he only works with 2 angles.

Comment: I think I have made it clear I am interpreting slightly different to you, enough to change the meaning of this answer. Instead of becoming hostile to negative feedback (if the asker thought this answer was ambiguous, it was ambiguous) you could consider ammending your answer to be more clear. At any point, instead of taking feedback you only seem to want to push discussion, and this is not the place. I gave you the chance to have the downvote undone - or reversed - but I will not be replying to your notifications any more, this is not constructive.

Comment: @Timelord64 Just wants to have the last word. Leave him and his absolute truth where he stands so that he'll be able to guide other as well as he guided you

Comment: @Bálint It was ambiguous in that it didn't clarify whether `.rotateX` and `.rotateY` are local or global rotations, which was the cause of my problem.